# How do I filter ForeignKey choices in a Django FilterSet?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I have a drop drop down list as in below image.It should only show the logged user campaigns (here the last free item. But it's showing the others users campaign.

[image]
Any help is apprecieated. Here are :

Is there a way to add parameter in my `{filter.form}` to show only the `logged item` and note the other `users's item`?

my `form.html` template:

```
<form class="#" method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     {% csrf_token %}
     {{filter.form}}
     <button type="submit">Search</button>
     <a href="{% url 'list_of_campaign_naming_tool' %}">Reset</a>
</form>
```

- Here is my view:

  ```
  def insertion_orders(request, pk):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        user = User.objects.get(id=pk)
        insertion_orders = user.insertionorder_set.all().order_by('-created_date')
        filter = InsertionOrdersFilter(request.GET, queryset=insertion_orders)
        insertion_orders_filter = filter.qs
        print(insertion_orders_filter)
        context = {
            'user': user,
            'insertion_orders': insertion_orders_filter,
            'filter': filter
        }

        return render(request, 'insertion_orders.html', context)
    else:
        return HttpResponse('You re not logged in ! Please log in first')
  ```
- My `model`:

  ```
  class UserInsertionOrder(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    campaign_naming_tool = models.ForeignKey(CampaignNamingTool,
                                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    budget = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2)
    goal_value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2)
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % self.campaign_naming_tool
        # return "{} - [{}]".format(self.insertion_order, self.user)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'InsertionOrder'
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Change the `insertion_orders` line to:

```
insertion_orders = user.insertionorder_set.filter(user=request.user).order_by('-created_date')
```

Next, try commenting out the next 3 lines below the line I requested you to modify.

Finally, change the context statement to:

```
context = {
          'user': user,
          'insertion_orders': insertion_orders,
          'filter': filter
      }
```

Comment: Lots of thanks. I tested it but I always the same problem

Comment: So, it's still showing the other users' items?

Comment: yes, It's still showing the oteher user's items eventhough I added the filrer as you suggested.

Comment: See my edited answer, please?

Comment: It didn't work. It couldn't work because we need to link the filter to the table to filter. So we couldn't only take insertion_orders versus insertion_order_filter